# Django: Convert form data into 'clean url'

Tags: python, html, django, forms, clean-urls

Let's say I have the following form:

```
<form id="search-form" class="form-horizontal" method="GET" action="/results/" role="form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="query" name="query">

    <button type="submit"  form="search-form" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>       
    </button>
</form>
```

Currently, when the form is submitted, the url contains the query as a parameter, like so: `www.<my-domain>.com/results?query=<some-query>`. However, for SEO purposes, I want to convert this to a 'clean url', which would look more like this: `www.<my-domain>.com/results/<some-query>`.

I've made the following modifications to my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^results/(?P<query>[a-zA-Z ]+)$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name="results"),
    ...
]
```

So I should be able to grab the query value in my ResultsView like this:

```
class ResultsView(TemplateView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        query = kwargs.get('query')
```

How can I submit the form so it'll match with the corresponding url pattern? I've tried fiddling with the form action passing the input id to it, like this: `action="/results/query/"`, but obviously, it thinks `query` is a literal string, and doesn't replace it with the value of the input.

Comment: You need to use Js for it because you can't paste input value as a part of url string like this `/results/query/` by standart django methods

Comment: @marni Yeah, that makes sense. I'm not that great at JS though. If you can post a working example, I'll mark the answer as correct.

Comment: even if you work with SEO purposes, you should use the GET method, is cleaner and easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with JQuery. When clicking the button, prevent default action, and define the url it should redirect to in the `window.location.href`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            query = $("#query").val();
            window.location.href = location.origin + "/results/" + query;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add dependency

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!